# Mapbox does not provide current location in devices that does not support Google play service

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have tried fetching location from Mapbox using the LocationLayerplugin, but it does not seem to work in devices that does not support Google Play Services. It works fine in devices that support play services.

Are we blocked to use location services in android devices that does not support play services?

Comment: LocationLayerPlugin uses location-core from https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/tree/master/liblocation/src/main/java/com/mapbox/android/core/location which supports using a non google play services location engine. eg the Android location engine.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this fixed our issue. But I am facing an issue with build generation after the latest mapbox update. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53541770/unable-to-generate-build-with-pro-guard-enabled-using-mapbox-sdk-6-7