# Unable to generate build with pro guard enabled using Mapbox SDK 6.7

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

Mapbox SDK: 6.7.0

After enabling the proguard in the gradle, we are getting the following error.

```
com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine: can't find superclass or interface com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngine   

com.mapbox.services.android.location.MockLocationEngine: can't find referenced class com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngine$Type
```

I have used LocationComponent, LocationEngine and LocationEngineProvider classes in my application. Do I need to add anything in proguard rules to generate a build with proguard enabled?

On commenting usages of these class, the build can be generated with proguard enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below lines in proguard file

```
-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine
-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.MockLocationEngine
```